# Creating a new Heuristics for AI

Tags: java, nodes, maze, heuristics

How to come up with a heuristic formula for a maze?
I needed to create a new heuristic algorithm to solve a maze.  It's a simple maze with a start node, goal node and several possible roads to connect them. The heuristic is to start from the start node to the goal node. A friend ended up using Euclidean Heuristic and just multiplying the value by 2. I'm trying to understand how this actually improve the heuristics.

Comment: You can adapt A* for the maze. Anyway are you sure you need to develop something completely new and the task is not just solving the problem with some heuristic.

Comment: You might have more success if you search for the word ["algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) instead of "heuristic." Also, is your objective just to solve the maze, or to come up with a "new" algorithm for solving the maze?

Comment: The answer is no, no you will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instructor knows very well that you're not going to be able to come up with a completely new heuristic that's practical and effective. That's the work of A.I. researchers with PhDs.

Do some research on heuristics that you haven't gone over in class, and draw inspiration from there, simplifying or varying one for better or worse. Just make sure you can talk about where you got the inspiration from as well as its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn and implement all of the algorithms exist in solving a maze problems.

Then you need to do a comparative study over them (Algorithms) you have found in step one. In this stage you are able to find the cons and pros of each method.

Now, you need to focus on one of the above methods and change the algorithm to fix one of its drawbacks or make it better. Creating a completely brand new heuristic method is not easy, making a contribution as our friend (Clumsysyrup) said is a PhD thesis and could take several years to come to a an acceptable result.

Keep in mind that to make an innovation you need to complete this cycle :

Data -> Information -> Knowledge -> Innovation

You just can't jump to the final step(innovation)